# Delete some files in a directory in php

Tags: php, regex, file, delete-file

I have a script which needs to delete some files starting with some pattern.

I tried `unlink`, but somehow didn't work, is there anything that am missing.

```
$files = glob(PATH_DIR.
    '_*.txt');
foreach($files as $file) { // iterate files
    if (is_file($file)) {
        //unlink($file); // delete file
        $mask = $var.
        '_*.*';
        array_map('unlink', glob($mask));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `array_map()` inside a loop? Which pattern are you looking for, `_*.txt` or `_*.*`? And what is `$var`? You don't define it in the code shown, but then try to use it in `$mask`, which is the basis for your call to `unlink()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@array_map('unlink', glob(PATH_DIR.'_*.txt'));
```

_- if not print all paths and then try to manualy trigger unlink

Comment: What about the `$mask` , i need to delete files starting with some pattern.

Comment: this is why you had *  you delete all like /_222.txt , try relace glob with die then you will be see what is incorrect, otherwise permission issue

Comment: Please don't recommend using `@` to suppress errors. This is very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

use   `RecursiveIteratorIterator` for getting files and also check you have enough permission to delete those files. Either `chown` that folder or change permission to `755` and files `644`

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} $path;
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} $path;
```

These commands will help to set permission recursively if you are on linux

```
$file_obj =  get_files_by_path('/var/www/html/wordpress')

foreach ($file_obj as $Ofiles) {
    $file_path = $Ofiles->getPathname();
    //use your regex here with $file path. if that passed then delete the file  

    unlink($file_path);
}

function get_files_obj_by_path($path){   
            $obj =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD
                );   
            return $obj;
        }
```